# Creating or enabling Shared Mailboxes when AD Split Permissions are in effect

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

In a new, on-premises Exchange 2016 environment — deliberately chosen to be installed with AD Split Permissions so that Exchange administrators could not accidentally delete AD objects — how is one *supposed* to create Shared Mailboxes?

The AD admin has created the User object representing the shared mailbox, but the EAC shows no <kbd>+</kbd> button under the `recipients -> shared` section, and the `New-Mailbox` PS cmdlet has no `-Type` or `-Shared` parameter.

The `recipients -> mailboxes` section has an <kbd>+</kbd> button, from which the Exchange admin can choose `User mailbox` and choose an existing user (they rightly cannot choose `New user`), and a user mailbox is created, but there seems to be no way to *change* it to be a shared mailbox.

Running `Set-Mailbox foo -Type Shared` in PS (against the user mailbox created in EAC) fails with `Insufficient access rights to perform the operation`.

Running `Enable-Mailbox foo -Shared` in PS (against the AD user created by the AD admin) succeeds, but warns `The ntSecurityDescriptor of the Active Directory object wasn't updated successfully` with further `Access is denied`/`INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS` wording.

If the AD admin has to do the legwork here, that's fine (within reason), but what do they actually have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I tested in my lab Exchange 2016 with AD split permission and also got this warning, however, the shared mailbox is created successfully via “Enable-mailbox xxx -shared”.

I did some research, and found [this similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/ce4b2c0b-86ee-4661-8ca8-8b1e8e3c7e1a/exchange-2010-and-resource-mailboxes-creation-problem?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy), you may refer to.

With AD split permission, some commands are not available and some commands although still are available, may offer only limited functionality.