# How to check if "Split Permissions" are set for an Exchange Server?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, exchange, exchange-2016

I need to administrate an Exchange Server where some powershell commands don't work (like `New-Mailbox`). It seems that "Split Permissions" are active on that installation but I'm not sure.

How can I check if split permissions are active?

Comment: You can view the available RBAC roles here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions/permissions?view=exchserver-2016

In general, if you seek admin-level permissions on Exchange, your account should be in "Organization Management" AD security group.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about split permissions enabled or not, you should check if which commands did not work for which account. And to find out what permission is needed/necessary to run this command in exchange 2016.

Answer (score -1):

What is the version of exchange server? Exchange 2013?
Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 offers the following types of split permissions models:
•   RBAC split permissions
•   Active Directory split permissions

And according to your description, I think you would like to use RBAC. The RBAC security model modifies the default management role assignments to separate who can create security principals in the Active Directory domain partition from those who administer the Exchange organization data in the Active Directory configuration partition.
And yes, RBAC is a component that exists on every server running Exchange 2013, and we didn’t need to “enable” it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/understanding-role-based-access-control-exchange-2013-help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's an Exchange Server 2016. Some powershell cmdlets which work on all other exchange servers (different customers) don't work there but I am not sure what's the cause of this behaviour. I found this question why I think that split permissions are active: https://serverfault.com/questions/956414/creating-or-enabling-shared-mailboxes-when-ad-split-permissions-are-in-effect (I will add some more informations when I'm back to office)